# Silverlight Binding to an item in a Dictionary

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, wpf-4.0

If I make the ViewModel definition to the following :

```cs
public class MainViewModel : DynamicObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Attributes["Welcome"] = "Welcome to MVVM Light";
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (Attributes.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = Attributes[binder.Name];             
        }
        else
            result = "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

In silverlight I get the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Welcome' property not found on 'DictionaryBasedVM.ViewModel.MainViewModel' 'DictionaryBasedVM.ViewModel.MainViewModel' (HashCode=30542218). BindingExpression: Path='Welcome' DataItem='DictionaryBasedVM.ViewModel.MainViewModel' (HashCode=30542218); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
```

The same works fine in WPF.

Comment: Have you tried making your ViewModel a [custom type descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx)?  I don't know if Silverlight supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this "{Binding Attributes[Welcome]}"

Comment: I was concerned about INotifyCollectionChanged implementation that will be required for this. Solved : http://www.basarat.com/2011/05/observabledictionary-for-silverlight.html And therefore accepted. There is still the issue of IDataErrorInfo though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `DynamicObject` only comes into play when a reference is held by an identifier typed as `dynamic`.

However Silverlight Xaml processing works with `object` not `dynamic` and uses reflection to determine the property info it needs.

One option as Oliver points out is to use Silverlight's ability to work with `string` based indexers.

Comment: Just FYI. I am using a viewmodel locator. The property for the viewmodel on the viewmodel locator is typed dynamic. The view binds it to its datacontext. But it still doesn't work. PS: I did not need to do this on WPF to get it to work. It just does.